# The renormalized fermionic operators do not anti-commute?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, fermions, effective-field-theory, anticommutator

Let's say we have fermionic operators $a$ and $b$ (which anti-commute). In the context of a renormalization scheme (I am thinking specifically of Wilson's NRG, but it could be DMRG) I have a matrix $P$ obtained from taking the $m$ lowest lying eigenvectors of the hamiltonian (each column is an eigenvector). To renormalize the operators, I define new operators $P'aP$ and $P'bP$.
However, since $P$ is a non-square matrix that comes from truncating the matrix of all eigenvectors, clearly $PP'$ is NOT the identity matrix. Therefore, the renormalized operators $P'aP$ and $P'bP$ have lost the anti-commutation rule. Isn´t this a problem?
I wrote a simple implementation of NRG and it works perfect for the energies (I compared with exact diagonalization for small systems), but the expected value of the number operator  in the impurity is wrong, and I wonder if it is related to this problem with the loss of anti-commutation rules and how to fix it.

EDIT:  Okey, I have realized that if I define at the beginning the number operator in the impurity and I renormalize it, I get the correct result. But still the confusion about the loss of the anti-commuation rules remains.